# How can I install mysql-python in a virtualenv without compiling anything?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I don't have access to gcc on my shared hosting provider (Hostgator), so when I try to install mysql-python from within a virtualenv using `pip install MySQL-python`, I get `unable to execute gcc: Permission denied`. Is there another way to install the MySQL-python library in my virtualenv?

Comment: Not that I know of. `pip` uses gcc. The package is much smaller precompiled.

Comment: One of `pip`'s less endearing qualities is that it doesn't provide binaries.

Answer (score 0):

There is the option for virtualenv of --system-site-packages which will "Give access to the global site-packages modules to the virtual environment."  If the parent host already has the mysql-python module installed, it will use that.

Comment: This worked for me for while creating virtualenv folder in hostgator shared hosting.